# which scoring function for validation_curve (regression)?

Tags: neural-network, keras, cross-validation, optimization

Is there any thumb of rule which scoring function should be used for e.g. the [validation_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve.html)?

Atm I try to study the difference between several optimizers:

```
validation_curve(grid_best 
                                          , X_train 
                                          , y_train
                                          , param_name = 'Adam', 'SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adamax', 'Nadam']
                                          , param_range = param_range 
                                          , cv=tscv
                                          , scoring="explained_variance" 
                                          , verbose = 1
                                          , n_jobs = n_jobs
                )
```

[image]

I use the `explained_variance` but I think the function has to be minimized cause the values are mostly below zero. That's why I think the explained variance does not make sense here?

edit:

When I use `r2` I get the following curve:

[image: nn]

Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `r2` for validating regression. It'd be much easier to compare different models. Here's [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), here's [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html).

Comment: Any explanation why R^2 over others? :)

Comment: It's not `r square` / `r^2`, it's just `r2`. It's much easier to compare this metric to other splits/experiments, as it converges to 1, 0 is constant answer, below 0 you're just bad.

Comment: sure, but why not e.g. rmse?

Comment: It's just easier to compare values that limits to `1`. With `rmse` it's harder to interpret results in a meaningful way.